# Expected end of line, etc. but found unknown token.- AppleScript Editor

Tags: javascript, ios, applescript, applescript-objc, applescript-studio

The scenario is , I'm going to pass some text to the LabelWriter Printer .. Its a sample for checking. But at compile time itself getting error.

```
 tell application "AppleScript Runner"

OPEN “COM1:9600,n,8,1” FOR OUTPUT AS #1 
PRINT #1, “HELLO WORLD”

end tell
```

Error: Expected end of line, etc. but found unknown token

Comment: `OPEN “COM1:9600,n,8,1” FOR OUTPUT AS #1` looks like BASIC or VBA. Are you sure that is valid AppleScript syntax?

Comment: To add to what @MartinR said, "COM1" is very much a DOS/Windows-ism.  OSX is Unix-based, and as such, serial ports will typically be specified as some device file in the /dev directory.  I am assuming that your physical serial port is provided by some external peripheral, so the name of the device file in /dev will be very much dependent on that.

Comment: Google has some interesting results - search for "applescript serial port".  In particular, it looks like you may need to install something like the SerialPort X scripting addition: http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/20440/serialport-x.  I have never seen this freeware before so can in no way endorse its functionality/reliability/safety.

Comment: anybody have idea that I can send a text to print . I have SDK and plugin for browser. I don't know how to use the sdk .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to the comments by Atomic Toothbrush.

This is a snippet from one of my old Applescripts that uses the built in Command line [*efax* (fax)[1](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/fax.1.html) program  to communicate with a modem.

```
set phone_num to "0207000000"
set thecall to do shell script "efax -v0 -d /dev/cu.modem -a TDT" & phone_num
```

I have also used the built in Command line program [Screen](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/screen.1.html) to receive data from a totem Bluetooth Modem. ( I do not have a snippet to hand at the mo. On an old mac which I will need to dig out)

But before you even get into trying this you should read up on [Applescript basics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html).